# Android read SMPTE timecode from video stream

Tags: android, live-streaming, timecodes

I am trying to read SMPTE timecode from a video stream. The SMPTE timecode was inserted by Adobe Flash Media Live Encoder.

Is there a function in the `MediaCodec` or `MediaPlayer classes that can do that (read the inserted timecode)?

I checked similar questions/answers in this website but couldn't find what I wanted.

I am still digging but I would appreciate if you can point me to the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

A bit late, but HLS livestreams supports ID3 tags, which you can use for timed events (jwPlayer supports that for example).